# Selenium java - TestNG configuring in Jmeter with out headless browser

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, jmeter

When we configure jenkins to run a TestNG script. I had to use the xVfb headless browser to run the test. What I want is to run it in the GUI mode. What's the best way to do this task ?

Comment: Have you provided Chrome or Firefox dependency in pom.xml and the subsequent driver call in test script?

Comment: I've been working on a Gradle-git project. Let's say it's not a maven TestNG project, in that case, we will face the same problem